# Silent Uninstall C#

Tags: c#, desktop-application, uninstallation

I have made a small desktop application using C# and I want to run the following string within a process in order to silent uninstall a program.
Here is a small part of my code:

string sFile=@”C:\Program Files\PROGRAM_I_WANT_TO_UNINSTALL\uninstall.exe /S”;

//Run the above uninstall script//

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sFile);

if I run in windows run the program is uninstalled, instead the application prompts with a message:
“the system cannot find the file specified”

Can you please tell what I an doing wrong?

Comment: I guess there is no program with a `/s` at the end of its name. You should pass that as argument.

Comment: See the duplicate how to correctly pass in arguments.